# How to get value from a query.list() by column name in Java

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a `SQL` query, where I have used join with more than 7 tables .

```
 SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("select e.id,e.name,e.email from emp as  e 
 inner join some 2/3 tables");
 List<Object[]> listObject = q.list();
 List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<>();
 for(Object[] result : listObject){
 Employee e = new Emplyee();
 e.setId(result[0].toString());
 e.setName(result[1].toString());
 emp.add(e);
 }
```

So instead of this I want to get value of `id` and `name` by column name, is there any way?

Comment: We have to use some data structure in java to hold the data coming from Database itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);` .
    `

```
try {
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         String sql = "SELECT firstName, salary FROM EMPLOYEE";
         SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
         query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
         List empList= query.list();
         for(Object object : empList) {
            Map row = (Map)object;
            System.out.print("FirstName: " + row.get("firstName")); 
            System.out.println("Salary: " + row.get("salary")); 
         }
         tx.commit();
      } catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      } finally {
         session.close(); 
      }`
```

Comment: By this I can get the column name I know, but I want to set value for each fields by their particular column name, like emp.setId(record[i].Employee_Id); something like this, what  we do in java script.

Comment: Your query is not clear can you please elaborate via any example what you exactly want to do?